# Salesforce: how to send email alerts on specific dates in salesforce using schedule apex?

Tags: apex, email, schedulebatch

I want to send email alerts to user which are lookup with account (user field is lookup in account) at the start of every quarter, based on a picklist.

My proposed picklist values, and their desired effects are:

- high

  - send an email once per quarter (4 times a year)
- medium

  - send an email every other quarter (2 times a year)
- low

  - send an email once per year

would pls any help on this.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a little clearer what you're asking for, but there are still improvements to this question that you'll need to make to prevent it from being closed (and to make it more likely that someone will answer you). On this site, it's generally a good idea to be _specific_. Saying "A lookup field to `User` on `Account`, named `Account_Manager__c`" is a lot better than saying "A user lookup", for example.

Comment: Also, your request sounds a bit too much like a "do my work for me" request. If you have some code that you've worked on already, please share it and point to a specific part that isn't working (and describe in detail what "not working" is, tell us what you expect to happen, what is happening, and the difference between them). If you're getting an error message, include the entire text of the error **verbatim**. If you don't have any code right now, I'd encourage you to write some code, and come back with a specific question if you get stuck (and try to search for similar questions first)

Comment: Hi Derek, actually i m administrator and implemented some formula fields to populate dates . using workflows i m trying to send email alert . condition is trigger == today date then it will fire email but records was not editing hence workflow not sending email. so i m trying to achieve this using scheduled apex  but i m not strong in apex so would please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom setting and specify the dates there and schedule the job  to run daily and match the current date with the date in the custom setting and if the date matches then send the email.

Comment: is this possible through workflow flow or process builder